# Lightweight cross platform database engine to work with my Qt Application

Tags: c++, database, qt, architecture

I am developing a Qt application to run on Windows, Mac and Linux (Ubuntu Desktop). Development is in C++ of course and it's a desktop application that needs to store and retrieve "tabluar" information on an ongoing basis.

I do not want to bother my users with pre-installing MySQL or anything alike.

Is there a lightweight database engine I can use as an SDK from my application that would store locally on the file system and support SQL queries?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try SQLite : http://sqlite.org

Comment: beat me to it by 15 seconds... :D

Comment: Qt has support for SQLite within it's database module as well. Just compile the included plug-in (or get a prebuilt Qt).

Answer (score 0):

I believe that [this (SQLite)](http://www.sqlite.org/) will do everthing that your asking in your question. From my own experience it work decently for small datasets. but if you are using it for large amounts of data, you may want to consider a full blow sql server